# ¿Cómo hacer que 2 links sean reemplazados por 1 en js?

Tags: javascript, href, enlace, replace

Tengo un problema, quiero que dos links distintos (link_01 y link_02) sean reemplazados por uno nuevo (link_03):

```
link = `a.href.replace((https://link_01.com, https://_link_02.com), 'https://link_03.com')`
```

¿Cómo agrupo link_01 y link_02 para que funcione? He probado entre paréntesis y con corchetes pero no reacciona. Sí que funciona esto:

```
link = `a.href.replace(https://link_01.com, 'https://link_03.com')`
```

Pero cuando añado el link_02 no hay manera.

Disculpad la manera de explicarme, no soy programador pero me lo han pedido y escapa de mi conocimiento.

¡Gracias de antemano!
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Tienes dos tag `a` y quieres remplazar ambos `href` por el link3 o es que tienes un solo tag `a` y quieres remplazar su `href` por el link3 ya tenga el link1 ó 2?

Comment: Con los tag me he perdido un poco, pero creo que es lo segundo que comentas. Quiero que el link1 y el link2 se reemplacen por el link3.

Answer (score 0):

En base a la documentación actual de la función replace sobre un Objeto String, su sintaxis es la siguiente:

- replace(Cadena a reemplazar o Expresión regular, Nueva cadena)
- Si el primer parámetro es una Cadena, sólo reemplazará la primera coincidencia.
- Si el primer parámetro es una expresión regular, reemplazará todas las coincidencias encontradas.

En tu caso, si tienes el link en mas de una ocasión, con añadir la función replace una vez para cada URL, no te valdrá. Por tanto, deberías utilizar una expresión regular para ambas URL, la cual puede ser expresada mediante su constructor o un literal:

```
var regex = '/https:\/\/link_0[1-2].com/' //literal
```

o

```
 var regex = new RegExp('https:\/\/link_0[1-2].com') //constructor
```

y finalmente:

```
a.href.replace(regex,'https://link_03.com')
```

Comment: Hola! He probado así pero no ha funcionado, pongo lo que he intentado:
 
          var regex = 'https://dominio.com/img/cms/Ambientes/'
          var regex = 'https://prepro.dominio.com/img/cms/Ambientes/'
          link = a.href.replace(regex, 'https://dominio.com/')

Comment: Las *regex* se definen entre *slashes* (`/`). `var regex = 'https:\/\/link_0[1-2].com'` es un string convencional. Para que sea una regex y haga lo que pretendes, debes iniciarla como `var regex = /https:\/\/link_0[1-2].com/;`. Y por favor, prueba tus respuestas antes de postearlas.

Comment: Tal y como comenta @VRoxa me despisté en el momento de escribir la expresión regular. Si la defines como un literal, tal y como hice yo, debe ir entre Slashes. Si la defines mediante el constructor, no es necesario.
En tu caso, tienes que tener en cuenta, que dentro de la expresión regular tienes slashes y al ser un carácter especial, tienes que añadir una slash invertido para que lo trate directamente como un caracter.

Comment: En tu caso sería:

var regex ='/dominio.com\/img\/cms\/Ambientes/' o
var regex = new RegExp('/dominio.com\/img\/cms\/Ambientes')
Además, en el ejemplo ten en cuenta que estas sobrescribiendo la variable regex, por lo que solo se aplicará en el segundo caso (prepro...).

Comment: Hola! Disculpad el retraso, he estado probando todo lo que me habéis comentado pero voy perdido. Creo que ya casi lo tengo de éste modo: `var regex = '/https:\/\/[prepro.]dominio.com\/img\/cms/Ambientes\//'` Tenemos dos direcciones, una que es (prepro.dominio.com) y otra que es solo (dominio.com) y pensaba que poniendo uno de las dos entre los corchetes funcionaría ésto: `link = a.href.replace(regex, 'otrodominio.com')` que es sustituir cualquiera de esas dos direcciones por (otrodominio.com) pero no me funciona, será que no tengo que ponerlo entre corchetes @Zito_MA ?

Comment: Ten en cuenta, que el punto también es un carácter especial, por lo que también tienes que añadirle el slash. Además, para la parte del subdominio prepro, añádelo entre paréntesis y a continuación un asterisco, que indica 0 o mas coincidencias de lo que está entre paréntesis. 
'/https:\/\/(prepro\.)*dominio\.com\/img\/cms\/Ambientes/'

Para probar tus expresiones regulares, puedes utilizar la siguiente herramienta :
- https://regexr.com/

Comment: Con eso ya funciona correctamente @Zito_MA!! Mil gracias por toda vuestra ayuda, me ha dado bastantes quebraderos de cabeza ésto. Un saludo!!

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado! No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta :)

Answer (score 0):

si tus elementos están impresos en el DOM puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

```js
var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll(['a[href="https://link1.com"]', 'a[href="https://link2.com"]']);

for (let i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    hrefs[i].href="https://link3.com";
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.